# FBSDKGraphRequest gives error "unsupported URL" while Fetching Event Attending list Facebook iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting attending list of Event by this code.

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken], @"access token",
                                @"100000000000",@"limit",
                                nil];

FBSDKGraphRequest *requestA = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/attending",[self.dictData objectForKey:@"FBEventId"]] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connectionA = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
        [connectionA addRequest:requestA completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if(!error)
            {
                attending = [[result objectForKey:@"data"] count];
                [tblDetail reloadData];
            }
            else
            {
                attending = 0;
                NSLog(@"error description : %@",error.description);
            }
        }];
        [connectionA start];
```

**This is working fine. But if i call it again, It gives me error,**

It seems like, It work only once.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7fe846142280 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe843ddcb90 "unsupported URL"}
```

I have access of these Permissions,

```
Permission : (
    "user_events",
    "user_friends",
    "rsvp_event",
    email,
    "publish_actions",
    "public_profile"
)
```

Is it enough to do this action ?
Why this is happening ??

Comment: Can you provide the ID of the event you want to query, and the (app scoped) ID of the user you are using? What is your App ID?

Comment: can't share it here. If you know the right method, post as answer.  App has been reviewed by FB and granted above permissions.

Comment: As long as I can't reproduce I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: cant share info here. App has been reviewed by FB and grated above permission.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution. Actual problem is in my graph request.

Here is a correct one.

```
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"100000000000",@"limit",
                                    nil];

        FBSDKGraphRequest *requestA = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/attending",[self.dictData objectForKey:@"FBEventId"]] parameters:params tokenString:[[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken] version:@"v2.3" HTTPMethod:self.HTTPGet];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connectionA = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connectionA addRequest:requestA completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            attending = [[result objectForKey:@"data"] count];
        }
        else
        {
            attending = 0;
            NSLog(@"error description : %@",error.description);
        }
        [tblDetail reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }];
    [connectionA start];
```